# no-cache, no-store, max-age on Cache control header

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

I am trying to understand the difference between these two cache headers.

In the first header, I have `max-age` twice - one with value 0 and another with value 600

```
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, max-age=600
Cache-Control →max-age=600
```

Can some help me with technically if both are same?

Comment: I don't think it's defined in the RFC what to do if there are conflicting cache directives like that.  If someone said turn left and right at the same time what would you do?